# Bootstrap Validator- does not submit form

Tags: jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the validator shown here, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YRGdvL, with a shopify contact form. When all the fields are valid, I click the submit form and the submit button grays out and nothing happens. If I edit one field and make it valid again, and submit, it works.

All I want is if the fields are valid, the submit button should be enabled and when clicked, it should submit the form as normal. You should not have to submit it twice.

```
on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
            console.log('success.form.bv');
        });
```

Update:
Solution was that I needed the jquery ID on the form tag, not the parent of the form. Then it worked.
`

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens. It is working as expected on the pen you gave.

Comment: Updated the link so you can see the action.